# My function's click only triggers when I click the link/button twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get instagram followers count through instagram API using JavaScript/jQuery.

There are multiple input fields each having its on button to get the followers count. I want each input field to be filled with respect to the button clicked.

Here is the code which returns the followers count which I bind with click function but for some reasons, the 'click even triggers only when I click the anchor/link second time.

```
function login_callback() {
    jQuery('.btn-instagram').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $t = jQuery(this);
        var $prevFolw = jQuery(this).prev('instaFollowers').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                access_token: accessToken
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var follows = data['data']['counts']['followed_by'];
                var link = data['data']['username'];

                alert($prevFolw);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

It should show the alert on first click.

Comment: why not just simply reigster event handler? why You've wrapped it inside functionn?

Comment: you are calling login_callback() then calling the event thats twice right??

Comment: oh, then any solution?

Comment: Move the `.click()` handler outside of the `login_callback()` function

Comment: where I am calling the function or where the function is defined?

Comment: We need to see where and how you call `login_callback()` to give you a solution to this

Comment: ^ remove the secret key from the comment. Not to be shared on public forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it solved by myself by binding both functions binding into one.

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     jQuery(".btn-instagram").click(function () {
     $th = jQuery(this);
        authenticateInstagram(
            'YOUR_INSTAGRAM_ID', //instagram client ID
            'YOUR_URL', //instagram redirect URI


   function (){ jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        access_token: accessToken
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var follows = data['data']['counts']['followed_by'];
        var link = data['data']['username'];

   $th.parent('.instagram-row').find('.instaFollowers').val(follows);
   $th.parent('.instagram-row').find('.instaURL').val(link);

   console.log($th.parent('.instagram-row').find('.instaFollowers').val());
  console.log($th.parent('.instagram-row').find('.instaURL').val(link));

      },
       error: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
      }
  })
  }         );

        return true;

        })
             });
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Before first click your buttons doesn't have `click` event and after first click it has event, this is why it working in second click. Put the `.click()` outside the function and Put your `login_callback()` in `success` nor `error` function.

```
function login_callback(data) {
  if (data == 'error') {
    alert('Login error!');
  }
  else {
    alert(data); // $prevFolw
  }
}

jQuery('.btn-instagram').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $t = jQuery(this);
  var $prevFolw = jQuery(this).prev('instaFollowers').val();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      access_token: accessToken
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var follows = data['data']['counts']['followed_by'];
      var link = data['data']['username'];

      //alert($prevFolw);
      login_callback($prevFolw); // <-- the callback

    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      login_callback('error'); // <-- the callback
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ewwink but it returns "undefined", whereas I want to show 'data' variable's value which is in success function.

Comment: `undefined` for which line? to show the data, in success function just change `login_callback($prevFolw)` to `login_callback(data)`

Comment: whatever I pass in the function, it returns "undefined"

Comment: you call `login_callback()` in button? it not needed the button will automatically have `click` event.

Comment: no, I am calling "login()" function in button. If you see my post and comments I have mentioned there  that the login function first calls the Instagram api and from there "login_callback()" is called as callback.

Comment: I'm confused, maybe you need to create jsfiddle with complete html and js.